# Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException - intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, flowable

The following error I'm getting while sending request body to the RestController in my spiring-boot application, the solutions available in the forum suggest the issue is related to IDE, but I couldn't find any QAs related to intellij,

```
 Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Merge
flowable-all-in-one-app_1  |    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:531) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
flowable-all-in-one-app_1  |    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(ContentType.java:255) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
flowable-all-in-one-app_1  |    at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.<init>(StringEntity.java:116) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
flowable-all-in-one-app_1  |    at org.flowable.http.HttpActivityExecutor.perform(HttpActivityExecutor.java:233) ~[flowable-http-6.4.0.jar:6.4.0]
flowable-all-in-one-app_1  |    at org.flowable.http.HttpActivityExecutor.execute(HttpActivityExecutor.java:94) ~[flowable-http-6.4.0.jar:6.4.0]
```

@RestController Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submission",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
    public void submission(@RequestBody Object variables) {
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: How you send your request ? do you use postmain , soapUi ?

Comment: @TinyOS I'm sending request via flowable workflow - its a BPMN engine

Comment: I do not khow that flowable :( but when you call your request what's your content-type ? i mean what you use as a charset ?

Comment: I would suggest trying to hit your `/submission` endpoint using Postman or curl, and specify the charset as `UTF-8` and see if you're getting the same error.

Comment: How does your HTTP request task look like? It seems like you have set a wrong value for the encoding.